# ZF2 Generate absolute URI from CLI

Tags: url, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I have a cron job which runs a ZF2 CLI route to send out some email notifications. The emails use an HTML view which I render via

```
$emailBody = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer')
               ->render('some/partial/name.phtml',$params);
```

Within this partial I use the view helper

```
<?php echo $this->url('some-route', array(), array('force_canonical' => true)); ?>
```

to generate an absolute URL to a page on my site. When I run this through a CLI however, I see an exception:

```
Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException
Request URI has not been set
```

Do I need to inject a dummy HttpRequest object into the view rendering service or should I approach this a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is running through the CLI there's no real way for the script to know the correct domain to generate an absolute URI.

I ended up creating a view helper at **module/Application/src/Application/View/Helper/CliDomain.php**

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class CliDomain extends AbstractHelper {
    protected $_config_protocol;

    protected $_config_domain;

    public function __construct(array $cliConfig) {
        $this->_config_protocol = $cliConfig['scheme'];
        $this->_config_domain = $cliConfig['domain'];
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        return $this->_config_protocol.'://'.$this->_config_domain;
    }

}
```

and configured the factory in **module/Application/config/module.config.php**

```
return array(
    ...
    'view_helpers' => array(
        ...
        'cliDomain' => function ($sm) {
                $config = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
                if (!isset($config['cli_url'])) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Please add a "cli_url" configuration to your project in order for cron tasks to generate emails with absolute URIs');
                }
                return new \Application\View\Helper\CliDomain($config['cli_url']);
            },
```

and in the project's **config/autoload/global.php** file I added a new key to the returned array

```
<?php
return array(
    ...
    'cli_config' => array(
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'domain' => 'prod.example.com',
    ),
);
```

for the staging server I added a matching config entry in **config/autoload/local.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    ...
    'cli_config' => array(
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'domain' => 'staging.example.com',
    ),
);
```

So in the question's view script I just prepended a call to the helper in the URL and don't bother forcing canonical.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->cliDomain() . $this->url('some-route'); ?>">a link!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass in an `Uri\Http` object to the `url()` view helper:

```
<?php
// at the top of your view script, or passed assigned to the view model
$uri = new \Zend\Uri\Http('http://www.example.com/subdir');
?>


<!-- within the view script -->
<?= $this->url('some-route', array(),
    array('force_canonical' => true, 'uri' => $uri)); ?>
```

or just code it in the view script:

```
http://example.com/subdir<?= $this->url('some-route'); ?>
```

(I'm assuming you're using PHP5.4 or higher, so you can use `<?=`)

Comment: True, but that negates the point of what I was trying to do: have the code generate an absolute URL to the correct environment. I'd was hoping to find a way for the cron job to generate emails with links to staging.example.com when on the staging server and prod.example.com when on the production server without having to change the view script's host